# TV mount above fireplace? HELP

Tags: electrical, fireplace, television, mount

I am moving into my first home and am wanting to mount my 43" flat screen tv above the fireplace. There are multiple outlets surrounding the fireplace, however there is not one above it. What are some ways to install this? Or some different ideas. I am set on putting it above the fireplace.

Comment: I think you should reconsider your set determination to place the TV above the fireplace. TV's are designed to give best viewing when you look directly into the screen at a 90 degree angle to the screen surface. It is also a pain in the neck to have to sit there staring up at the TV. Lastly there is the elevated heat issue that is not friendly to electronics when the fireplace is blazing away.

Comment: Need to know more about the fireplace. Is it a brick fireplace, stone fireplace, gas/wood insert in a chase, etc.  Is there a basement/crawlspace below, or attic above?

Comment: we install TV's over fireplaces all the time for lots of people. there are no issues with heat (assuming your fireplace is in good working order), but there are with smoke (if its a wood fireplace). just leave 6in minimum between mantle and bottom edge of the tv. if you want to install a new outlet, you have to add more detail about the construction and surrounding area. the process to add an outlet behind the tv could be simple or incredibly complex. if you want to go a simpler route, you can get a rectangular plastic raceway, stick it to the wall and run your cabling through it. you can pain

Comment: Ditto what @MichaelKaras said.  I asked a professional installer the same question.  He said, "I won't do it.  Everybody asks for a TV above the fireplace, but nobody is _ever_ happy with it once it's  been done."